# Installing libsndfile1 on docker container

Tags: docker, libsndfile, soundfile

I'm trying to install soundfile over pip install on my docker container. Sadly i need to install `libsndfile1` manually over `apt get` by myself. This fails somehow and i don't really get why and does anyone know how to install it.

I'm running docker desktop on Win10 - but container will finally run on a Linux machine.

```
 > [ 7/11] RUN apt-get install libsndfile1:
#11 0.618 Reading package lists...
#11 1.814 Building dependency tree...
#11 2.219 Reading state information...
#11 2.829 The following additional packages will be installed:
#11 2.830   libflac8 libogg0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
#11 2.942 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#11 2.944   libflac8 libogg0 libsndfile1 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
#11 2.956 0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
#11 2.956 Need to get 669 kB of archives.
#11 2.956 After this operation, 2136 kB of additional disk space will be used.
#11 2.956 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install libsndfile1]: exit code: 1
```

Anyone know something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command with an automatic yes to make it run non-interactively.

```
RUN apt-get --yes install libsndfile1
```

And FYI - this dangerous `--force-yes` option too is available.

Use with absolute discretion if necessary.

Read about apt-get options [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).